# Do both: Fontend and Backend Unittests?

Tags: unit-testing

I wanted to ask if there is any best practice or so if you should write unittests for backend and frontend seperatley. In more detail: We have a Frontend which sends ajax requests to a backend API server. If we test the frontend and check there if everything is correctly, do we even need backend tests? Or is it better to split those 2 into Front-End and Back-End tests. If so why?

Comment: This questions can't be answered because it heavily depends on your setup and personal preferences on testing strategies. Besides you are talking about integration tests. Unit tests are usually very small tests written for single classes or methods.

Comment: Thanks for the info, may i ask what your personal preference is and why? Do you write your test all in the frontend, or do you seperate them?

Comment: I usually do test driven backend development and very rarely to never do frontend tests. Full stack integration tests are imho usually very bulky, slow and often only used for testing very straight forward things that would be noticed anyway right away when not working(e.g. login works). Unittests are very lightweight to write, execute in milliseconds and are perfect for testing all the very specific edge cases. That said, I do use both but its like 98% of my tests are unittests and then some integration tests to see if everything fits together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main purposes of software testing is to fix the expectations of functionality. An Interface should do the same thing, even after a refactoring.

An unit test checks usually the correctness of a single interface, which can be a class or a function. A unit test should run fast and catch errors in a early stage. If an error occurs it is easily to find the reason, since few code is covered by the test.

An integration test checks the interaction between multiple components. If an error occurs it is much harder to find the reason, since the error can be in one of the components or in the interaction between the components.

Based on this I would suggest, you write seperate unittests for the backend and the frontend. You can use mocks to simulate the backend, if the frontend would need the interaction. Additional you write integration tests, which checks complex interactions between the front and backend.

Answer (score 1):

Testing should always be separate between front and backend. If you are trying to test an API you could use utilities like Postman runner to write tests and check that all the functionalities of the API are working correctly.

For instance, if your API is written in Laravel / Lumen, you could write their own unit tests.

It is personal preference though, it heavily depends too of the policies of your company, or in your personal setup.

Comment: Thanks. Can i ask why you prefer seperating them? I will give you a simple example e.g. "Login" if you write a test in the frontend using selenium and can confirm that you are logged in, is it still required to test the backend login function? Are there any downsides only doing frontend or is it all just personal preference?

Comment: @Tobias that is quite a simple case, but imagine you are trying to store something in the database, you should try to test it from the frontend, whether it is manually or with unit testing, and then it would be good to test it in the backend again, just in case there is something that might crash. However, I would say it is personal preference, but I always try to be sure the app is working correctly from both sides.

Answer (score 1):

you can look at it this way ....

if you have back-end code then you should cover it with unit tests.
if you have front end code then you should also cover that with unit tests.

You threw Selenium in there and Selenium has nothing to do with unit testing. That's a UI test there and those are slow and brittle.

As a rule of thumb if you write code, doesn't matter where, with some sort of business values, rules etc, then test that.

If you build an API then cover it with unit tests and integration tests.
Whatever system you build, if it has a UI then you should have a few UI tests as well, to make sure things still work, but don't go too hard on those because anything that relies on UI to automate tests is likely to change so the maintenance cost will be high.